# How to change the label of bLengthChange in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Is there any way to change the label of dataTables_length or bLengthChange?..
I already tried this link, http://datatables.net/ref#sinfo , I tried oLanguage.sInfoEmpty but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "*MENU*"
        }

Answer (score 6):

This is what you have to do.

Add `"lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page"`, to language, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
             ....
        }
    } );
} );
```